# How to concatenate two dataframes in pandas?

Tags: python, dataframe

There are two dataframes.

How to concatenate element-wise?

You can see the code [here](https://repl.it/@Chan2019/MurkyRingedExternalcommand)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['string1', 'string2'])
df1.loc[len(df1), :] = ['Hello', 'This is Sam']
df1.loc[len(df1), :] = ['Good?', 'Are you free']

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['string1', 'string2'])
df2.loc[len(df2), :] = ['how are you?', 'from Canada']
df2.loc[len(df2), :] = ['morning', 'to have a talk?']

df1

  string1       string2
0   Hello   This is Sam
1   Good?  Are you free

df2

        string1          string2
0  how are you?      from Canada
1       morning  to have a talk?


#How to get the desired dataframe: [['Hello how are you?', 'This is Sam from Canada'], ['Good morning?', 'Are you free to have a talk?']]
```

Comment: "How to get the next row:"...  I see two rows? Not 1. And where does the result go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the index and columns are the same, use any of the following DataFrame string concatenation operations.

```
df1 + ' ' + df2

              string1                       string2
0  Hello how are you?       This is Sam from Canada
1       Good? morning  Are you free to have a talk?
```

---

```
df1.add(' ').add(df2)

              string1                       string2
0  Hello how are you?       This is Sam from Canada
1       Good? morning  Are you free to have a talk?
```

---

```
df2.radd(df1.add(' '))

              string1                       string2
0  Hello how are you?       This is Sam from Canada
1       Good? morning  Are you free to have a talk?
```